# error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype.

Tags: java, android, ооп

Не работает alertdialog во фрагменте

Код `fmonday.java` (P.S.: Чтобы код не получился слишком длинным, я удалил некоторые куски где используется loader):

```
public class fmonday extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
final int DIALOG_ITEMS = 1;
final CharSequence[] items = {"1", "2", "3"};
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fmonday, container, false);
    Button button12 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button12);
    button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            getActivity().showDialog(DIALOG_ITEMS);
        }
    });
}
@Override //Здесь ошибка
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_ITEMS:
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            adb.setTitle("Adding class");
            adb.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Your choice: " + items[item],
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            adb.setCancelable(false);
            return adb.create();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

logcat:

> Error:(88, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Замените родительский класс Fragment на DialogFragment

Comment: В базовом классе Fragment нет метода onCreateDialog. Он есть в классе DialogFragment.

Comment: @АндрейКасьянов , @SergeyGornostaev , изменил родительский класс на `Dialog Fragment`, ошибка осталась та же. Не помогло

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не верно указали сигнатуру метода (тип возвращаемого значения, имя метода, список аргументов(их кол-во, порядок и типы)) и создали новый, не существующий в классе метод, после чего сказали, что этот метод якобы существует в супер-классе.
IDE заметила вашу ошибку и сказала об этом.

На этом этапе вам надо было заглянуть в [доки](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) и убедиться, что в классе `DialogFragment` нет метода `Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)`.

Зато есть `Dialog   onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Итого вы допустили ошибку в списке аргументов метода, а именно в типе аргумента, написав `int` вместо `Bundle`.