# Выдает ошибку: cannot find symbol class OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

```
b.setOnClikListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick (View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this,
                ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте указать полный путь у интерфейсу View.OnClickListener:

```
b.setOnClikListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this,
                ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Также, не лишним будет указать аннтацию переопределения метода. Но это не обязательно.

Comment: аннотация точно [ничего не изменит](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/467665/177345)

Comment: @pavlofff, но и хуже не будет, тем более, что вы по ссылке сами написали, что её отсутствие может привести к трудно вычисляемой ошибке. Вот, недавно [пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523091/17609) был, где прописанная, но необязательная аннотация помогла найти ошибку.

Comment: @pavlofff, она ничего не изменит, тем не менее я бы лично презрительно посмотрел бы на человека, который их умышленно убирает.

Comment: @metalurgus Конечно вы оба правы, я лишь хотел сказать, что это не может быть решением проблемы, то есть от отсутствия, либо наличия аннотации, проблема не возникнет и не решится.

Comment: @pavlofff, немного отредактировал ответ